# Convert String into Integers representing a date

Tags: java

I need to turn a string that represents a date into a date.

A date is constructed like this:

```
private int m;
private int d;
private int y;

public Date(int month, int day, int year) {
      if (isValidDate(month, day, year)) {
          m = month;
          d = day;
          y = year;  
      } else {
          System.out.println("Error: not a valid date");
          System.exit(0);
      }
  }
```

The string that needs to be converted into this date object is in the format:

```
"month/day/year"
```

The month is 1 or 2 characters, the day is 1 or 2 characters and the year can be 1 - 4 characters.

My idea was to loop through the string and find when the character `/` appears but I feel like there is a better way of going about it.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=date+format+java

Comment: There is already a `Date` class in Java (and a `DateFormat` to do what you need). I'd suggest not reinventing the wheel or, at least, not to use the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use`String.split("/")

It returns array of strings for each token and then you just need to parse each one into an integer and create the date object.`

You might want to look into DateFormat class as well.  It may be able to parse the string for you.

EDIT:

A static factory method instead.

```
public static Date asDate(String s) { 
    String[] dateStrings = s.split("/"); 
    int m = Integer.parseInt(dateStrings[0]); 
    int d = Integer.parseInt(dateStrings[1]); 
    int y = Integer.parseInt(dateStrings[2]); 
    return new Date(m, d, y);
}
```

Comment: I worded the question wrong: I need to make another constructer that takes the date as a String. I tried this but it gives me an error of "constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor." This is what I have: 
`public Date(String s) {
          String[] dateStrings = s.split("/");
          m = Integer.parseInt(dateStrings[0]);
          d = Integer.parseInt(dateStrings[1]);
          y = Integer.parseInt(dateStrings[2]);
          this(m, d, y);`

Comment: If possible, I would suggest using a static factory method instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so:

```
String date = "14/02/2013";
String [] splitDate = date.split("/");
Date date = new Date(Integer.parseInt(splitDate[0]),
                     Integer.parseInt(splitDate[1]),
                     Integer.parseInt(splitDate[2]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this code can help you.

```
public class TestDate {

    private int m;
    private int d;
    private int y;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String date = "02/14/2013";
        String[] splitDate = date.split("/");
        TestDate td = new TestDate();
        td.Date(Integer.parseInt(splitDate[0]),
                Integer.parseInt(splitDate[1]), 
                Integer.parseInt(splitDate[2]));
        System.out.println(td.m +"/"+td.d+ "/"+td.y);
    }

    public void Date(int month, int day, int year) {
        if (isValidDate(month, day, year)) {
            m = month;
            d = day;
            y = year;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: not a valid date");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    private static boolean isValidDate(int month, int day, int year) {
        String stDate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        try {
            sdf.parse(stDate);
            return true;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can use methods of the string class to get your substrings, or use some kind of string tokenizer (i don't know java well, so can't help you with exact names).
But "under the hood" these functions too must iterate through the string, there is no way around it.
so your idea is good i think. it's only a matter of wheter you want to master the built in possibilities in java, or you just want to get it over with quickly :)